# Ionic 2 Tab color change with events

Tags: ionic2

How can I change the tab color using an event? For example I am adding a product to cart. Raise the number of cart while doing so. But instead of this, I added the cart product and I want to change the color of the cart tab option. How can I do it ?

```js
<ion-tabs no-border>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Giriş" tabIcon="ios-home"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Ürünler" tabIcon="ios-pizza"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" (ionSelect)="barkodTara()" tabTitle="Barkod" tabIcon="ios-barcode"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab4Root" tabTitle="Hesabım" tabIcon="ios-contacts"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab5Root" tabTitle="Sepet" tabBadge="{{ SEPETSAYISI }}" tabBadgeStyle="danger" tabIcon="ios-cart"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

for example, can I do this with the help of a class?
[Application IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Crqb.png)

Comment: please provide a bit of your template code of the element you want to change its color.

Comment: @Sonicd300 ok I added

Comment: This is not out of the box in ionic, you will have to roll your own css solution

Comment: @Sonicd300 Could you explain a sample to me?